# Angular 2 rollback model state in forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form in Angular 2 which is bound to a model. Now I want the changes in the model to rollback when the user hits cancel. How do I achieve this?

Comment: See the discussion of the RestoreService here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Comment: @MarkRajcok: This wont work because my model is also bound to another component and all the changes in the form has to be reflected in that component _while_ the user is editing the form.

Comment: Make a copy of your model before you display the form.  If the user cancels, revert to the copy, and notify the other component to use the copy also.

Comment: @MarkRajcok, thats what I am doing right now. I thought there may be a better way of doing this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll repeat what was discussed in the comments (because I don't like unanswered questions on SO):

- For many use cases, you can probably use something very similar to the RestoreService that is discussed in the [Hierarchical Injectors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html) dev guide.
- For the OP's particular case, where the model is bound to another component and live form changes need to be reflected in the other component, make a copy of your model before displaying the form.  If the user cancels, revert to the copy, and notify the other component to use the copy also (i.e., send it the copy).

Answer (score 0):

If you make a copy of your model by doing `Object.assign({}, yourModel)` you won't mutate the original object, which will allow you to revert to the original object.